# Cannot see available network page after updating to KB4346783

Tags: networking, windows-10, windows-update, window, windows-10-v1803

I just updated my laptop using Windows 10 1803 using the cumulative update package (KB4346783). Everything is working great except I cannot click on network taskbar icon and see available network connections.

I am already connected to Wifi, and it's working fine. But I cannot to another one beacuse that page is not showing up. Uninstalling the update seem to fix it for me.

How do I fix it without uninstalling the updates.

**Edit:** As a temporary fix (if you want to install latest updates), I am able to access available network connection page through lock screen. So just lock your computer, and connect to wifi from that screen.

Comment: +1 for testing uninstallation.

Comment: You need to confirm, if you uninstall the update, the problem goes away.  I assume you have tried to reboot your machine since you installed the update?  The confirmation that it is indeed the update causing this behavior, is required, in order to formulate an answer to this question.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes it is. I tested it on two different laptops. Installing this update caused it in both, and system restore fixed it

Comment: I wasn’t able to reproduce on any device I have.  This sounds like a driver issue.

Comment: @ramhound it seems to be UI issue. See me edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out (by checking event logs), ShellExperienceHost was crashed during the update because of my firewall software.

Reinstalling shell experience host fixed the problem for me.

```
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```